# Drop and Create Stored Procedure from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I wish to create a temporary stored procedure from within some c# code. Although it is a temporary stored procedure I wish to drop it if it already exists to ensure if the connection has remained open I don't get issues when I try to create it a second time.

I have SQL along the following lines for this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#usp_GetSomething') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP PROC #usp_GetSomething
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE #usp_GetSomething
    @Table VARCHAR(100) 
AS  
BEGIN
    SELECT @Table
END
```

This is valid SQL and executes in Management Studio.
However when I use the following C# to execute it:

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand(theSQL, sqlConnection) {CommandType = CommandType.Text};
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I get the following error:

*Incorrect syntax near 'GO'. Must declare the scalar variable "@Table".*

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the SQL to execute?

Comment: (I've simplified the actual stored proc)

Comment: Have you tried removing `GO`?

Comment: @JDHooper That isn't valid SQL. "CREATE PROCEDURE must be the only statement in the batch"

Comment: @andrew and GO is not a t-sql keyword either. It is the default batch terminator in SSMS. You will have to run this as two batches. That means two separate calls to the database. But since this is a temporary stored proc it is kind of pointless to check. You do close the connection after you use it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need the DMO/SMO namespace in there to do that.

simple SqlCommand wont help.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

> This is valid SQL

This is wrong.

GO is not a SQL keyword. It is a batch separaor that is recognized by SSMS and IIRC SQLCmd.

From code, you must split this SQL into multiple statements (at every GO) and submit them separately.

Answer (score -1):

Use `StoredProcedure` instead of commandtext like below :

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var command = new SqlCommand("ProcedureName", conn) { 
                           CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure }) {
   conn.Open();
   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: That throws the following: The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. The RPC name is invalid.

Comment: You set the type and length of your first parameter here

command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@errMessage", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 8000));
If the length of the parameter is different (larger or smaller) than the length specified in the database you will get an error.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I would use that approach for a stored procedure I'm trying to execute, but I don't have a parameter that I need to set the value for. The parameter is within the stored procedure I'm trying to create.